# MYSQL Many to many query to same table

Tags: mysql, sql

`TABLE A` below is a many-to-many table I have that references the same table `TABLE X`, and I have another `TABLE B` that references `TABLE X` as well. I would like to create a query that maps the two tables.

TABLE A

```
measure_id | related_measure_id
   1       |     2         
   1       |     4         
   1       |     5        
   2       |     3
   2       |     4         
   2       |     6        
   3       |     5
```

TABLE B

```
  id    | name    | measure_id
   A    | Adam    |     1         
   B    | Bill    |     2         
   C    | Cate    |     2        
   D    | Dale    |     3         
   E    | Emma    |     3         
   F    | Fawn    |     4         
   G    | Gale    |     5         
   H    | Hale    |     5
   I    | Iale    |     5
   J    | Jake    |     6
```

Desired output:

```
  id    | name    | id2 | name2
   A    | Adam    |  B  | Bill   
   A    | Adam    |  C  | Cate        
   A    | Adam    |  F  | Fawn       
   A    | Adam    |  G  | Gale
   A    | Adam    |  H  | Hale
   A    | Adam    |  I  | Iale
   B    | Bill    |  D  | Dale
   B    | Bill    |  E  | Emma
   B    | Bill    |  F  | Fawn
   B    | Bill    |  J  | Jake
   C    | Cate    |  D  | Dale
   C    | Cate    |  E  | Emma
   C    | Cate    |  F  | Fawn
   C    | Cate    |  J  | Jake
   D    | Dale    |  H  | Hale
   D    | Dale    |  I  | Iale
   E    | Emma    |  H  | Hale
   E    | Emma    |  I  | Iale
```

Attempt:

```
select b.id, b.name
from tableB b
join tableA a1 on b.measure_id=a1.measure_id 
join tableA a2 on b.measure_id=a2.related_measure_id
```

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on db-fiddle, it should work.

```
SELECT B1.id AS id, B1.name AS name, B2.id AS id2, B2.name AS name2
FROM tableA AS A
JOIN tableB AS B1
    ON A.measure_id = B1.measure_id
JOIN tableB AS B2
    ON A.related_measure_id = B2.measure_id
```

[db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7VM3LHfRJq99ski5LYinh5/1)

Comment: Give the columns aliases so you can tell the difference between `B1.name` and `B2.name`.

Answer (score -1):

I think something like this should work

```
select b1.id, b1.name, b2.id, b2.name
from tableA a, 
join tableB b1 on a.measure_id = b1.related_measure_id
join tableB b2 on a.measure_id = b2.related_measure_id
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't fully understood the question, but isn't b1 and b2 are the same table which we are trying to show. (I a newbie in MySQL)

Comment: The query idea is good, but there is a comma too many and you mixed up the measure IDs.